# Html link href attribute <a href="./"> explanation

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

I just find out that **href** value can be **"./"** **`<a href="./">`**
As it looks like, target is previous folder > index file

What else could be set for href attribute except protocols (ftp, http, etc, relative path)?

I feel like I've discovered something undiscovered...

Comment: Just FYI, if it's a single dot and then a slash like you have in your post, that means it is targeting the current folder. If there is a double dot and then a slash "../", that means it targets the previous folder.

Comment: @Ekaterina yes, my mistake! Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing. You either have an absolute URI (which has a scheme) or a relative URI (which does not). In short: It must be a URI.

Relative URIs can be relative to either the current base URI, the host root or the scheme.

Using `./` to indicate the current directory has been a staple of relative paths for decades (it predates the WWW).